# Taking 4 digit number in c code

Tags: c

Im trying to take 4 digit number from user in c language.

1)  I have tried using    `scanf("%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);` 
When I compile the code i write the numbers (1234) and enter the code does not execute after pressing enter.

2) I tried  :

```
a=getche();
b=getche();
c=getche();
d=getche();
```

but when using `getche` a,b,c,d saving as char not integer. And the code didn't work properly again. 
What should i do? How can i take 4 numbers from user and save every digit in different integer?

Comment: 1234 is a single number, not four.

Comment: Read it as string.

Comment: scanf ( "%1d%1d%1d%1d", &a, &b, &c, &d); worked ty so much!

Comment: Good alternative to know: `char a; a=getche(); int n=a-'0';`

Comment: Good alternative to know: char a; a=getche(); int n=a-'0';    I didnt  know that ty so much!

Comment: @user3121023 Why is that a comment and no answer?

Comment: @Beta Why is that a comment and no answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Because it appeared that the OP had already chosen the approach given in another comment, and I didn't want to get points for an inferior solution.

Comment: @Beta I am impressed by your moral standards (in case this seems sarcastic: I am serious). However, if you get upvotes for it, then it is because somebody sees some value in a secondary, different solution. It is a hard to predict question of opinion, whether you might actually end up with a negative score... In my opinion, it does not deserve any downvotes - no upvotes either, but any upvote you get is deserved. OPs opinion is the foundation for the "accept tick", but that is all. Anyway, I only wanted to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. That desire has been covered. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way just enter the entire numbers and they will be separated:

```
int number, result;
printf("Please, enter four numbers: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (number > 0) {
    result = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    printf("%d\n", result);
}
printf("\n");
```

**The result:**

Please, enter four numbers: 1234
4
3
2
1

Answer (score 0):

`How can i take 4 numbers from user and save every digit in different integer?`

Because there are some good comments about your problem I'll stick to the Question.

If you need to inform the User about its wrong input like:

```
1f
```

or:

```
g2
```

Something like this could be a good choice:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checkInput(void);

int main(void){
    int a = checkInput();
    int b = checkInput();
    int c = checkInput();
    int d = checkInput();

    printf("\nYour numbers are:\n");
    printf("A = %d\n", a );
    printf("B = %d\n", b );
    printf("C = %d\n", c );
    printf("D = %d\n", d );

    return 0;
}

int checkInput(void){
    int option,check;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Please type a number:\t");

        if(scanf("%d%c",&option,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check = getchar()) != 0 && check != '\n');
            printf("\tI sayed a Number please\n\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);

    return option;
}
```

Output:

```
    Please type a number:   2
Please type a number:   1f
    I sayed a Number please

Please type a number:   1
Please type a number:   g2
    I sayed a Number please

Please type a number:   3
Please type a number:   4

Your numbers are:
A = 2
B = 1
C = 3
D = 4
```